# Подсчёт данных пользователя из других таблиц SQL запрос

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT "user".username, "list".slug , "follower",
count("list".slug) AS listCount,
count("follower".user_id) AS followers
FROM "user" JOIN list  ON list.owner_id = "user".id 
JOIN follower ON follower.user_id = "user".id 
WHERE "user".username = 'mokybrow' GROUP BY "user".username, "list".slug, "follower"
```

Всем привет, есть такой запрос, нужно подсчитать количество подписчиков и количество списков пользователя, если не группировать, то считает не правильно, а сгруппированный результат разбивает на единицы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте использовать подзапросы вместо джоина. ```count("follower".user_id) AS followers => (select count(*) from followers f where f.user_id=user.id) as followers```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков "=>" вот за такой знак пишет ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: было => стало, замените свой count, на select, и уберите джоин этой таблицы =)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  u.username, 
  (select count(*) from list     l where l.owner_id= u.id ) AS listCount,
  (select count(*) from follower f where f.user_id = u.id ) AS followers
FROM 
  "user" u
WHERE 
  u.username = 'mokybrow'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Или может так?

```
SELECT
  "user".username,
  COALESCE(l.listCount, 0) AS listCount,
  COALESCE(f.followers, 0) AS followers
FROM
  "user"
  LEFT JOIN LITERAL (
    SELECT
      COUNT("list".slug) AS listCount
    FROM list
    WHERE
      list.owner_id = "user".id 
  ) l ON true
  LEFT JOIN LITERAL (
    SELECT
      COUNT("follower".user_id) AS followers
    FROM follower
    WHERE
      follower.user_id = "user".id
  ) f ON true
WHERE
  "user".username = 'mokybrow'
```

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае надо было добавить distinct ответ пришёл случайно, когда искал похожие задачи

```
SELECT "user".username,
count(distinct  "list".id) AS listCount,
count(distinct "follower".follower_id) AS followers,
count(distinct "passed_game".game_id) AS passedgame
FROM "user" 
left outer JOIN list  ON list.owner_id = "user".id 
left outer JOIN follower ON follower.user_id = "user".id 
left outer JOIN passed  ON passed.user_id = "user".id 
left outer JOIN passed_game  ON passed_game.list_id  = "passed".id 
WHERE "user".username = 'mokybrow' GROUP BY "user".username
```